# RichTextBox foregound colors and Runs

Tags: wpf, data-binding, richtextbox

I have a TextBox control:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding MyText},.../>
```

where

```
MyText = "leftWord/rightWord";
```

I understand that to get multiple foreground colors I cannot use a TextBox but rather a TextBlock or RichTextBox.  Since I need to edit the text, I will use a RichTextBox.

My goal is to highlight (change the foreground color) either "leftWord" or "rightWord" in the displayed text depending on the value of another property, such as

```
MyChoice = Left|Right
```

I am not sure how I can set the Run content to the right characters based on the MyChoice property.  Is there a way I can pass the entire text to a converter, along with the value of MyChoice and somehow have that set the correct foreground colors?  If so, I am not sure what the xaml would look like.

Would this be possible with a RichTextBox? I notice it has no Text property so I am not even sure how to bind (two-way binding) MyText to it.

Comment: Tricky because the `Inline`/`Block` properties aren't dependency properties.  I'd maybe extend `RichTextBox` and add your own "Text" dependency property to it.

Comment: @dbaseman: If I did go ahead and add a "Text" property myself, any idea on how in that case I would be able to set foreground colors?

Comment: I'm thinking you could add Runs (with the appropriate Foreground color) to the `Inlines`/`Blocks` collection whenever the "Text" property is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 variables with .substring(#,#); and then effect those variables foreground color based on the condition